# Join multiple collections in mongodb and keep all fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am new to NoSQL databases, and I got a little confused with collection aggregation. Here is what I am trying to do: I have three collections: `productCollection`, `detailsCollection` and `brandCollection`.
`productCollection` has the following fields: `_id`, `name`, `details`
`detailsCollection` has `_id` and `brand`
`brandCollection` has `_id` and `name`

These collections also have other fields, but these are the most interesting for me. As you may guess, `details` in `productCollection` is a reference to `_id` in `detailsCollection`, while `brand` in `detailsCollection` is a reference to `_id` in `brandCollection`. What I need is to get the collection with products and their brands. So, basically, I need to join these three collections and extract `name` from `productCollection` and `name` from `brandCollection`

So far, I managed to write this script:

```
db.productCollection.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "detailsCollection",
         localField: "details",   
         foreignField: "_id",  
         as: "det"
      }
   },
   
   {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$det", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
   },
   
   { $project: { "det": 0 } },
   
   {
       $lookup: {
           from: "brandCollection",
           localField: "brand",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "br"
       }
   },
   
   {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$br", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
   },
   
   { $project: { "br": 0 } }
])
```

It shows me all the fields in all three collections, but it does not show me the brand's name. I think it might be because the field `name` appears in both `productCollection` and `brandCollection`. All other fields are fine.
Hence, my question is: how do I make `name` from `brandCollection` appear in the result too? Maybe I can rename it in the process to be shown under another name? And is there an easier way to join these three collections? Or is the script above fine?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: can you post sample/example dataset of both collections and expected result.

Comment: I have something like this: 

`productCollection`:

`[{'_id' : 1, 'name' : 'Laptop Dell 22inch', 'details' : 2}]`


`detailsCollection`:

`[{'_id' : 2, 'brand' : 7}]`


`brandCollection`:

`[{'_id' : 7, 'name' : 'Dell}]`

Comment: And the expected result would be: `[{'_id' : 1, 'name' : 'Laptop Dell 22inch', 'brand' : 'Dell'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$lookup` with `detailsCollection` collection
- `$lookup` with `brandCollection` and pass `localField` as brand id
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from `brand` result
- remove `details` field its no longer needed

```
db.productCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "detailsCollection",
      localField: "details",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "brand"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "brandCollection",
      localField: "brand.brand",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "brand"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      brand: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$brand.name", 0]
      },
      details: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N3zM-6JJWn5)